# Determine if user navigated from mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile-safari, web-clips

I have an app, and I'd like to redirect the users to different pages based on where they are navigating from.

If navigating from web clip, do not redirect.
If navigating from mobile Safari, redirect to safari.aspx.
If navigating from anywhere else, redirect to unavailable.aspx

I was able to use [iPhone WebApps, is there a way to detect how it was loaded? Home Screen vs Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738766/iphone-webapps-is-there-a-way-to-detect-how-it-was-loaded-home-screen-vs-safari) to determine if the user was navigating from a web clip, but I'm having trouble determining if the user navigated from mobile Safari on an iPhone or iPod.

Here's what I have:

```
if (window.navigator.standalone) {
    // user navigated from web clip, don't redirect
}
else if (/*logic for mobile Safari*/) {
    //user navigated from mobile Safari, redirect to safari page
    window.location = "safari.aspx";
}
else {
    //user navigated from some other browser, redirect to unavailable page
    window.location = "unavailable.aspx";
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038625/detect-if-device-is-ios

Comment: @Ali that question isn't asking for the same thing as this one

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**UPDATE**: This is a very old answer and I cannot delete it because the answer is accepted. Check [unwitting's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007480/determine-if-user-navigated-from-mobile-safari/29696509#29696509) for a better solution.

---

You should be able to check for the "iPad" or "iPhone" substring in the [user agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) string:

```
var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;

if (userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) {
   // iPad or iPhone
}
else {
   // Anything else
}
```

Comment: I think it's not. How about different than safari iOS browsers? I think this expression will exclude not only Safari, but all iphone/ipad browsers.

Comment: this is not the right answer because if I access it from chrome for ios it will return true

Comment: This doesn't work, because the user could be browsing with Mobile Chrome on iOS, now, and this would still return true even though it's not Mobile Safari.

Comment: This does not detect if the user is for example using mobile Chrome. And Chrome iOS has a very ancient javascript engine (due to Apple's policy) in comparison to Safari, making some rendering impossible.

Comment: It does include iOS Chrome, but since iOS Chrome is just Safari with a different UI, for all intents and purposes this is fine.

Comment: This shouldn't be marked a correct answer as it includes any browser running on iPhone. The question specifically ask to detect mobile safari.

Comment: This is obviously the wrong answer. Use `navigator.vendor` as well to check if it's Safari. See my answer below.

Answer (score 188):

See https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent#chrome_for_ios_user_agent - the user agent strings for Safari on iOS and for Chrome on iOS are inconveniently similar:

*Chrome*

`Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 5_1_1 like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/534.46.0 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/19.0.1084.60 Mobile/9B206 Safari/7534.48.3`

*Safari*

`Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543 Safari/419.3`

Looks like the best approach here is to first of all check for iOS as other answers have suggested and then filter on the stuff that makes the Safari UA unique, which I would suggest is best accomplished with "is AppleWebKit and is not CriOS":

```
var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
var iOS = !!ua.match(/iPad/i) || !!ua.match(/iPhone/i);
var webkit = !!ua.match(/WebKit/i);
var iOSSafari = iOS && webkit && !ua.match(/CriOS/i);
```

Comment: @fabricioflores c'est la vie :(

Comment: +1 The only answer here that covered all the specs. I would just change the iOS test regex to `/iP(ad|hone)/i` so you don't need the or.

Comment: @sareed don't forget iPod

Comment: @sareed I always found it astoundingly satisfying to be able to regex iP(ad|od|hone)

Comment: Stupid Opera on iOS would still pass true on the code above, so I changed the last line to this:
var iOSSafari = iOS && webkit && !ua.match(/CriOS/i) && !ua.match(/OPiOS/i);

Comment: Nice answer. But why using a double negative (!!) with match when you can use test()?

Comment: @OMA no reason. Just an arbitrary choice for an example where performance isn't really a consideration :)

Comment: Simulating IPhone with Chrome desktop, it returns something like 
_Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; Nexus 6 Build/LYZ28E) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.96 Mobile Safari/537.36_. 
I would extend the already provided answer to
`var iOSSafari = iOS && webkit && !/(Chrome|CriOS|OPiOS)/.test(ua)`

Comment: @HumanA. and in order to exclude Microsoft Edge on iOS, I added  !ua.match(/EdgiOS/i), so the full version looks like this: var iOSSafari = iOS && webkit && !ua.match(/CriOS/i) && !ua.match(/OPiOS/i) && !ua.match(/EdgiOS/i);

Comment: Mobile chrome is still passing this check

Comment: can confirm this works, and so is: 

```!!window.navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) && !!window.navigator.userAgent.match(/Safari/i)```

Comment: that it shouldn't have `CriOS` is not enough to determine that it is indeed Safari. It only tells us it's not Chrome. Firefox on iOS has `FxiOS` instead

Comment: This is not 100% efficient as this will not filter out Firefox for ios , and Opera for ios, or any upcoming browser, we need an expression that checks specifically for safari ios

Comment: Latest IPad Safari user agent does not contain "IPad" any more. It's replaced by "Macintosh". This means this solution failed to detect safari on new IPads.

Answer (score 27):

best practice is:

```
function isMobileSafari() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/) && navigator.userAgent.match(/AppleWebKit/)
}
```

Comment: That would also match for Chrome iOS :(
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13808053/668157

Comment: This detects mobile chrome as well.

Comment: How should we differentiate between iOS Safari and iOS Chrome then? Any ideas?

Comment: these two regexes can easily be combined

Comment: this matches Desktop Safari too.

Answer (score 12):

Merged all the answers and comments.
This is the result.

```
function iOSSafari(userAgent) {
    return /iP(ad|od|hone)/i.test(userAgent) &&
      /WebKit/i.test(userAgent) &&
      !(/(CriOS|FxiOS|OPiOS|mercury)/i.test(userAgent));
}


// Usage:
// if iOSSafari(window.navigator.userAgent) { /* iOS Safari code here */ }

// Testing:
var iPhoneSafari = [
  "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_4_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1",
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Apple-iPhone7C2/1202.466; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543 Safari/419.3",
  "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A5341f Safari/604.1",
  "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A372 Safari/604.1",
  "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A5370a Safari/604.1",
  "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1",
  "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone9,3; U; CPU iPhone OS 10_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14A403 Safari/602.1",
  "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone9,4; U; CPU iPhone OS 10_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14A403 Safari/602.1",
];
console.log("All true:", iPhoneSafari.map(iOSSafari));

var iPhoneNotSafari = [
  "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/69.0.3497.105 Mobile/15E148 Safari/605.1",
  "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) FxiOS/13.2b11866 Mobile/16A366 Safari/605.1.15",
];
console.log("All false:", iPhoneNotSafari.map(iOSSafari));
```

Comment: I'm guessing this also matches desktop safari (`WebKit`)

Comment: @antoine129 No it doesn't (tested on OS X El Capitan) - the regexzzzz are ANDed and I guess Desktop Safari does never send iP* ...

Answer (score 9):

Falling code only find mobile safari and nothing else (except dolphin and other small browsers)

```
  (/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/gi).test(userAgent) &&
  !(/CriOS/).test(userAgent) &&
  !(/FxiOS/).test(userAgent) &&
  !(/OPiOS/).test(userAgent) &&
  !(/mercury/).test(userAgent)
```

Comment: This is the only one that differentiates Firefox and Opera on iOS.

Answer (score 6):

Seeing all the answers, here are some tips about the proposed RegExes:

- `AppleWebKit` matches Desktop Safari too (not only mobile)
- no need to call `.match` more than once for such simple regexes, and prefer the lighter `.test` method.
- the `g` (global) regex flag is useless while the `i` (case insensitive) can be useful
- no need for capture (parenthesis), we are just testing the string

I'm just using this since getting `true` for mobile Chrome is OK for me (same behavior):

```
/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent)
```

(I just want to detect if the device is a target for an iOS app)

Comment: Important remarks about the regular expressions (in general), thanks for pointing this out here (where most got it wrong)! In addition to your answer, one should nowadays check for `!window.MSStream` as well to exclude Microsoft’s browsers as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9039885/89818) to another question. And `!/CriOS/.test(navigator.userAgent)` is for those who want Chrome filtered out as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13808053/89818).

Answer (score 3):

This regex works for me, clean and simple:

```js
const isIOSSafari = !!window.navigator.userAgent.match(/Version\/[\d\.]+.*Safari/);
```

Comment: This won't work with embedded WKWebView if the host app doesn't explicitly add `Safari` into a custom user-agent string.

Comment: iPad Safari is now lying by default.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there isn't a silver bullet of detecting mobile safari. There are quite a few browsers may use the keywords of the user agent of mobile safari. Maybe you can try feature detection and keep updating the rule.

Comment: No in my case, for example. I want to show custom smart banner made for iOS+Chrome, but not show this banner on iOS+Safari, because iOS+Safari already have a built-in smart banner.

Comment: @JobaDiniz I know many people want to do something just in mobile safari but not in other browers, so do I. However, as a matter of fact, browsers which match tokens like "iPad", "iOS", "iPhone" .etc don't mean they are mobile safari, maybe they are some other browsers for iOS. For example, UC and QQ browsers in China. All these browsers may use the core of safari and most behaviors are the same as mobile safari, but some not. It sucks.

Comment: It sucks indeed. Foolish of me I had hoped that navigator.appname would be different, all iOS browsers are 'Netscape'. Yet, Safari is the only one capable of installing Configuration Profiles, so if any other gets a .mobileconfig, it download it and looks stupid because it does not know which app can open it...

Answer (score 1):

I upvoted @unwitting 's answer, as it inevitably got me going. However, when rendering my SPA in an iOS Webview, I needed to tweak it a bit.

```
function is_iOS () {
    /*
        Returns (true/false) whether device agent is iOS Safari
    */
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    var iOS = !!ua.match(/iPad/i) || !!ua.match(/iPhone/i);
    var webkitUa = !!ua.match(/WebKit/i);

    return typeof webkitUa !== 'undefined' && iOS && webkitUa && !ua.match(/CriOS/i);
};
```

The main difference being, the renaming of `webkit` to `webkitUa`, so as to prevent clashing with the root `webkit` object used as a message handler between the SPA & UIView.

Comment: This worked.  return typeof webkitUa !== 'undefined' && iOS && webkitUa && !ua.match(/CriOS/i);

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I'd like to share my solution with you guys.

I needed to detect when an user navigates from Desktop Safari (Because we're in middle 2017, and Apple hasn't give any support for `input[type="date"]` YET...

So, I made a fallback custom datepicker for it) . But only applies to safari in desktop because that input type works fine in mobile Safari. So, I made this Regex to only detect desktop Safari. I already tested it and it doesn't match with Opera, Chrome, Firefox or Safari Mobile.

Hope it may help some of you guys.

```
if(userAgent.match(/^(?!.*chrome).(?!.*mobile).(?!.*firefox).(?!.*iPad).(?!.*iPhone).*safari.*$/i)){
  $('input[type="date"]').each(function(){
    $(this).BitmallDatePicker();
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this answer and I remembered I came across this before.

The most reliable way to detect Safari on iOS in JavaScript is

```
if (window.outerWidth === 0) {
    // Code for Safari on iOS
} 

or 

if (window.outerHeight === 0) {
    // Code for Safari on iOS
}
```

For some reason Safari on iOS returns 0 for window.outerHeight property and window.outerWidth property.

This is for all iPads and iPhones on all versions of iOS. Every other browser and device this property works normally.

Not sure if they intend to change this but for now it works well.

Comment: doesn't work anymore for at least ios >= 14 :/ as of 20230617

Answer (score 0):

Based on [unwitting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29696509/1202683) answer here is regex if someone needs it.

```
/^(?=.*(iPhone|iPad|iPod))(?=.*AppleWebKit)(?!.*(criOS|fxiOS|opiOS|chrome|android)).*/i
```

Comment: the AND condition is well explained here.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240765/is-there-a-regex-to-match-a-string-that-contains-a-but-does-not-contain-b

Answer (score 0):

It's been many years and Apple still hasn't fixed their bottom fixed positioning (`100vh`) bug on mobile Safari.  Even though every other browser works fine.

So, There's also a vender property that'll say "Google, Inc" for Chrome and even Brave, other Webkit browsers if the userAgent is Webkit Safari unless it says "Apple Computer Inc." in which case it's Safari.

To avoid false positives in Desktop Safari, you need the maxTouchPoints property as well, which will be 5 for mobile and 0 for desktop.  Horrifying, I know.

```
const isSafari =
  navigator.userAgent.match(/safari/i) &&
  navigator.vendor.match(/apple/i) &&
  navigator.maxTouchPoints;

if (isSafari) 
  $("body").classList.add("mobile-safari");
```

Then make adjustments in the CSS using that `mobile-safari` class.

Answer (score -1):

```
function isIOS {
  var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
  return /(iPad|iPhone|iPod).*WebKit/.test(ua) && !/(CriOS|OPiOS)/.test(ua);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var isApple = false;    
if(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {      
  isApple = true;
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.