# Switch href url with javascript/jQuery for desktop to mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

Hi guys I can't seem to find the exact thing I am trying to do, and being a javascript amateur I can't seem to wrangle it.
Basically...
I have this script attached to various elements on my page

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("h1, h2, h5, .class1, .class2 #image1").click(function () {
    window.open('https://www.linkdesktop.com');
});
```

});

and what I want to do is:
IF on mobile device THEN switch www.linkdesktop.com TO www.linkmobile.com

Is this possible, do I do it based on screen size or using some sort of mobile detect script?

Answers appreciated, thanks a lot.

---

Ok so thanks for the answer

so perhaps somthing like this?

```
    var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;

$(document).ready(function() {
if( (Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry).test(navigator.userAgent) ) {

$("h1, h2, h5, .class1, .class2 #image1").click(function () {
    window.open('https://www.linkmobile.com');
});

}
else {

$("h1, h2, h5, .class1, .class2 #image1").click(function () {
    window.open('https://www.linkdesktop.com');
});

}

});
```

Answer (score 1):

In my last project I've used this [solution to check mobile user](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/11/detecting-mobile-devices-with-javascript/). Elegant and simply.

```
var isMobile = {
  Android: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
  },
  BlackBerry: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
  },
  iOS: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
  },
  Opera: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
  },
  Windows: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
  },
  any: function() {
    return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
  }
};

if( isMobile.any() ) alert('Mobile');
```

Comment: Ok thanks so if I use your method with variables declared above this is should work:
' $(document).ready(function() {
if( isMobile.any() ) {

$("h1, h2, h5, .class1, .class2 #image1").click(function () {
    window.open('https://www.linkmobile.com');
});

}
else {
 
$("h1, h2, h5, .class1, .class2 #image1").click(function () {
    window.open('https://www.linkdesktop.com');
});

}

}); '

Comment: Yes it will. But instead to declare the isMobile var globally, i would put isMobile inizialization and declaration inside $(document).ready(function(){ var isMobile = {...}; ); <- like so.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the user agent (window.navigator.userAgent), see [Determine if user navigated from mobile Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007480/determine-if-user-navigated-from-mobile-safari)