# Detecting iOS-WebApp and changing CSS attribute

Tags: javascript, ios, css, web-applications, detection

I know there exist several topics about this problem but I couldn't find a solution which works for me.
So here is my problem:
My website is responsive and shows an info-box when it's loaded from a mobile device. This info-box shows a link to a tutorial how to save the website as WebApp. When the user loads the website from a WebApp the info-box should be hidden.
Here's the code I'm using (not working):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (window.navigator.standalone == true) {
    document.getElementById('alertbox')[0].style.display = 'none !important';
  }
</script>
```

The info-box has the ID "alertbox":

```
<div id="alertbox" class="alert alert-info visible-phone">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
  This website supports iOS-WebApps. Learn more <a href="/guides/ios-webapp">how to save this website as WebApp</a>.
</div>
```

the "!important" tag is neccessary because I'm using Twitter's BootStrap and they defined a sub-attribute (display) already as !important.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your javascript at end of the page to make sure `alertbox` is available in `DOM` at the time you are trying to change its `css`? Or may be use some `DOM ready` callback if you have `jQuery` already included.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I moved the script from the <head> to the end of the html after including the bootstrap.js file but it still doesn't work. Could you please explain me what you mean with the "DOM ready callback" ? I'm completely new to JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright after searching the web and testing various combinations I've found the solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod touch|iPhone|iPad|CriOS)/i)) {
    if (window.navigator.standalone == true) {
      //iOS WebApp
      $(".alert").alert('close');
    }
    else {
      //iOS Safari/Chrome
    }
  }
  else {
    //other browser
    $(".alert").alert('close');
  };
</script>
```

The script above automatically dismisses the alertbox with this code:

```
<div id="alertbox" class="alert alert-info visible-phone">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
  This website supports iOS-WebApps. Learn more <a href="/guides/ios-webapp">how to save this website as WebApp</a>.
</div>
```

I hope I could help the people who might have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is your answer? 
[Determine if user navigated from mobile Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007480/determine-if-user-navigated-from-mobile-safari)

I hope this solves your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this doesn't work for me. Either I did something wrong with the CSS command or the "!important" tag doesn't get added correctly.

Comment: @Aeon In that case try some `alert('hi');` inside the if condition instead of changing the `css`. So you can be sure if the condition is working.

Comment: I've tried that. I added a message before and after the CSS command but only the first message shows up. Seems like the CSS is wrong. Any ideas?