# Is there a way to detect iOS safari while filtering out iOS Chrome, Firefox and other browsers?

Tags: javascript, ios

So for those who worked on iOS web applications probably know that due to Apple's policy, Chrome and other mobile browsers on iOS use a very ancient javascript engine. This is why we need to disable some of the rendering for Chrome and other none-safari browsers for iOS.

I had been reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007480/determine-if-user-navigated-from-mobile-safari) and there is no useful answer there. Here are some of my approaches (failed):

Use `is_iOS = navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g)` to detect if the browser is on iOS. And then use:

`is_FF = navigator.userAgent.match(/(firefox)/g)` and `is_Chrome = navigator.userAgent.match(/(chrome)/g)`

to kill off those firefox and chrome browsers.

I then realized all the browsers share identical user agent string with iOS safari. So I imagine the method should be running a javascript function that only Safari can run and then determine if the browser is Safari.

Comment: Might I suggest filtering based on features instead of `userAgent`? For instance: `if (window.localStorage) .....`.

Comment: @blex I realized all the browsers share identical user agent string with iOS safari. So I imagine the method should be running a javascript function that only Safari can run and then determine if the browser is Safari.

Comment: @KJPrice please explain more. This seems to be the right solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, there's two schools of thought when choosing which native functionality you should use while working in browsers. One school of thought is checking the `userAgent` as you are doing here and using/removing features based on the `userAgent`.

The problem with checking `userAgent` is that it gets complicated really fast. You have already run into an interesting problem, but what will happen when you find that ie8 does not have the feature you are looking for?

A better solution may be to check if the feature exists in its current context without worrying about `userAgent`. A great example would be the new HTML5 `audio` element. Based on [browser support](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp), we can tell that it does not exist in ie8 nor Safari < 4.0. Instead of checking if the browser matches the ones mentioned here you can just check if the **feature** exists. As we know that the `audio` element is an instance of the `Audio` class. We can simply check:

```
if (window.Audio) {
    //load and play the HTML5 audio element here
}
```

That is much simpler than checking the `userAgent`.

Comment: That definitely provided a good idea! I tried using `window.localStorage` as the detecter and unfortunately both Safari and Chrome returned `true`.

Comment: Well then `localStorage` works for those browsers. What you said you said here "we need to disable some of the render for Chrome", what do you need to disable?

Comment: In my case specifically I created a javascript rendering engine that can run video directly on the page as the background (instead of calling for the video player), but the frame rate is very low for non-Safari browsers.