# How can i detect, if webpage is running in iPad in-app browser?

Tags: php, facebook, ipad, detection

Is there a way, in php, to know if a webpage is running in the facebook in-app browser?

When I post a link on facebook, I need to know, if the user views the webpage through the facebook App for iPad, or through facebook viewed on the iPad safari browser.

I know that i can detect the iPad, but this is not sufficient, since both the facebook App and the facebook through a browser will be running on an iPad.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too had this problem today.
I was comparing the Useragent-Strings and came up with a solution, that works for me.
Quick and dirty:

```
function check_ios_fb() {
$uagent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$return = false;
    if(preg_match('/FBBV/i',$uagent))
    {
      if(preg_match('/iPhone/i',$uagent))
        $return = true;
      if(preg_match('/iPad/i',$uagent))
        $return = true;
    }
    return $return;
}

if(check_ios_fb()) {
    echo 'This page is viewed in the facebook inApp browser on iPhone or iPad';
  } else {
    echo 'This page is NOT viewed in the facebook inApp browser';
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might work for you...

```
if (
("standalone" in window.navigator) &&
!window.navigator.standalone
){

// .... code here ....
}
```

Check source:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1950-Detecting-iPhone-s-App-Mode-Full-Screen-Mode-For-Web-Applications.htm

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i need it to be server-side. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

"I'm not sure about Android, but when you're using the iOS SDK's UIWebView, it sends the name and version of your app as part of the user agent (YourApp/1.0)."

You can then use PHP to check if your in-app webview is being used or not:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'YourApp/') !== false)
```

I think Android does something similar as well.

Source:
[Detect in-app browser (WebView) with PHP / Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383776/detect-in-app-browser-webview-with-php-javascript)

Hope this works for u

Answer (score 1):

this is not complete solution but you can try like this for IOS (iPad/iPhone etc.) and Others

```
$internalBrowserOS = '';
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'FBAN') !== FALSE) {
    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'iPhone OS')) // or iPad
        $internalBrowserOS = 'iPhone';
}else if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'FB_IAB/FB4A') !== FALSE){
        $internalBrowserOS = 'androidOrAnotherOne';
}
```