# How can I determine if user is viewing from internal Facebook Browser?

Tags: php, html, facebook, apache

Is there any way that I can determine if user is viewing my website from internal Facebook Mobile application browser or from Safari? Does it send any HTTP data or agents that could give me that information ?

Comment: Have you checked the user agent header, and have you googled e.g. browser id-ing? Safari should be very easy to detect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect in-app browser (WebView) with PHP / Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383776/detect-in-app-browser-webview-with-php-javascript)

Comment: well I would get a hold of one of these mobile do-hickies and test it out.. lol ...seriously that's the best way to find out, although there is likely to be variation from device to device.