# Xamarin.ios : Error Code 530001 in SSO login

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory, xamarin.ios

In my Xamarin iOS application, I am showing a website using Xamarin web view. However, I am facing an issue with the SSO login functionality for that website, it showing a 530001 error code in sso login. The error logs indicate that the device identity is missing when sending a request from the Xamarin app. It is worth noting that the SSO login feature is working fine on Safari.

error logs

Error Code: 530001
Device identifier: Not available
Device platform: Android
Device state: Unregistered

[image]

AD team confirms From the logs, that DeviceID is null when called from the Xamarin web view but it shows a valid value when called from the device browser. I am unsure of where to begin troubleshooting this issue.

Comment: Your post includes no meaningful detail we could use to assist you

Comment: I don’t know much about this topic, but maybe you need to add to the user-agent string being sent. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34000300/199364 .  See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/34000129/199364, which discusses differences in what is sent from an app browser window, vs an actual browser.

Comment: Please see the attached image in the question to view the error details. 
AD team has confirmed that there is no browser-specific policy, and the error is being caused because the device identifier is missing @jason