# detect in-app browser for Telegram

Tags: javascript, php, inappbrowser, telegram

How we can detect (with client JS or server PHP language) that our page is requested for displaying by **in-app browser**?

i see [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383776/detect-in-app-browser-webview-with-php-javascript) in stackoverflow but i want to do this in Telegram messenger.
i see [useragentstring.com](http://www.useragentstring.com/) in Telegram in-app browser and in chrome browser. both show a exact same result:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; ASUS_Z00LD Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.81 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

is there any suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: I would be surprised if Telegram used a custom browser. They're probably just using a WebView or something similar. [See this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460205/detect-ipad-iphone-webview-via-javascript)

Comment: ok. i just need to detect that my page loaded in "in-app browser" or in serparated chrome app.

Comment: Then read the question I linked to. It should help.

Comment: thanks. that may work only in iOS. i see "not iOS" message in android phone.