# apple touch icon/home screen icon click event for web app

Tags: jquery, html, apple-touch-icon

I want to run a piece of javascript code when apple touch icon/home screen icon of my web app is clicked ,how can i get the click event for this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you really looking for an event? Or do you want to know if your web page was loaded though an apple touch icon click or regular browsing?

In the later case, your question was already asked:

- [iPhone WebApps, is there a way to detect how it was loaded? Home Screen vs Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738766/iphone-webapps-is-there-a-way-to-detect-how-it-was-loaded-home-screen-vs-safar)
- [Determine if user navigated from mobile Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007480/determine-if-user-navigated-from-mobile-safari)

However, I was *not* able to use the `window.navigator.standalone` technique described in the answers. You should study this carefully.

Comment: Hi yes i really want that click event to run my code.