# How can I detect whether a user has installed a specific iPhone app via JavaScript?

Tags: iphone

I'd like to build a mobile Web app that:

- If my iPhone app is already installed, launches it by redirecting to a URL handled by the app

  If my iPhone app is not installed, displays a web page encouraging users to download it from the App Store

The problem is, I don't know how to detect whether the app is installed before redirecting.  Does anyone know a trick for doing this?  Maybe a JavaScript hack of some sort, leveraging the App registered URL in an iframe or similar?

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108693/is-it-possible-to-register-a-httpdomain-based-url-scheme-for-iphone-apps-like-y/1109200#1109200

Answer (score 0):

You very likely can't do this. Even in a native app, all you can call is UIApplication's canOpenURL: method, which just tells you if *some* app will open the URL, not which one. I have no idea if this function is exposed in JavaScript; very likely not (I wouldn't want malicious javascript probing my phone for which URLs it can open).