# add custom URL Schema using http://

Tags: iphone

I want to add a custom URL to my iPhone app so other apps will be able to open it,
However I want the URL to begin with "http", in more details, I want to open the app form a link in an email i've sent to the user and the link has to be valid that if the email is read from a desktop computer he will be redirected to the site.

I know that there are apps that do so -like youtube that reacts to http://www.youtube.com

However I'm not sure whether Third party app can

Thanks,
Guy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to register a http+domain-based URL Scheme for iPhone apps, like YouTube and Maps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108693/is-it-possible-to-register-a-httpdomain-based-url-scheme-for-iphone-apps-like-y)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to run the link through your site first.

For example, the link in the email could be `http://<YOUR_SITE>/Q9xDH364`

And this link could take them to a special page on your site. On your site, if you detect the user agent from an iPad/iPhone/iPod, you can display an alert that says something like:

> If you have "MY APP" installed on your device, you can view this link in your app

Then, if the user presses ok, translate the `http://<YOUR_SITE>/Q9xDH364` link into a link your app can get, such as `my_app://<YOUR_SITE>/Q9xDH364`

This works well for my app, [Ambiance](http://bit.ly/ambiance).  For an example, go to http://snd.am/35 from your iPhone and your browser and see the differences.

Answer (score 1):

This does not work for third-party apps. Only Apple's own apps can react to certain http:// links.

Comment: does Apple has a document describing that?