# Can my iPhone app register its own launch URL with a http schema, rather than a custom one?

Tags: iphone, url, ios4

Ive implemented this feature in a few apps without issue, but have yet to test whether it will handle custom web urls, like the YouTube and GoogleMaps apps do.

As Im not at a mac I thought Id pose the question as it will be useful for other people.

This question suggests its possible, but doesnt say how without using a 3rd party service: [add custom URL Schema using http://](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223014/add-custom-url-schema-using-http)

It may seem a stupid question but one of my devs needs to know and Im not there to help/test this at the moment

Comment: The question doesn't say how, but its answer does.

Comment: Indeed but thats not an answer really to my question, thats using a 3rd party service not the app itself

Answer (score 2):

Yes! Here's a very nice tutorial on it: http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html

Comment: Thanks I've read that but we've tried using http as the custom url schema with that method and it doesnt work

Comment: @tigermain - Post your code. I promise the API works. Something's going wrong in your implementation of it.

Comment: Hi Dan, Im not sure what to say, I've just looked at the code and we ARE doing exactly what the tutoral says in order handle custom schemas but if we use http as the schema nothing happens - if we test from safari in the simulator that is

Comment: @tigermain - Dunno... I've never done it myself, just know it's possible and there are apps doing it.

Comment: The article clearly explains it. You two are talking about two different things. The OP wanted to use `http` *instead* the custom one; the article only explains how to do it with custom ones. No, this is not possible. Something must have changed in iOS8, since YouTube does exactly what the OP wanted (unfortunately I still don't know how)