# Detect installed iPhone App using PHP?

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

is this possible somehow?

I would like to redirect to different pages depending on whether the user already installed an app or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is completely impossible for your server to reliably tell whether an app is installed on the client.

(Unless you can associate app users with page viewers by user account)

Comment: I registered an URL Scheme in my info.plist. Might it be possible to recognize whether safari would respond to the URL-Scheme?

Comment: No, it wouldn't be possible. (at least from the server)

Comment: Well I guess then I can only show a page with 2 links, one to the store if the app is not installed, one to the app if it is installed. Then the user has to decide, which is an ugly extra step...

Comment: If you're okay with using javascript and have registered a URL Scheme on your app, than it is possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108693/is-it-possible-to-register-a-httpdomain-based-url-scheme-for-iphone-apps-like-y/1109200#1109200

Answer (score 0):

Not really possible. You can launch the app using the custom URL scheme but the user will get a Safari error dialog if the app isn't installed.

I guess your app could ping the server with some unique session ID when it launched and you could send this back to the web page using Ajax as a success validation..  Seems like a lot of work and pretty fragile.

It may be possible to detect the safari error dialog with some clever JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

This would be a pretty significant privacy violation. A phishing site, for example, could determine which banks I use by looking for their iPhone apps on my phone. Apple's not going to permit that, let alone make the data available deliberately.

Comment: If the app must explicitly publish the data, it wouldn't be (such) a privacy hole.  However, it's still impossible.