# Using Browser I want to do open a url,for doing payment

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, safari

In my iPhone app using Browser I want to open a url for processing a payment.
When webpage loads a button is displayed, on clicking the button a new page opens in a new window.
On that page user enters the payment details and payment is processed.
After payment we are directed to a success page.

The question is, how do I return to my application after payment?

Comment: Are you OK with Apple taking 30% of your transactions? If you process payments in an iOS app, Apple want their 30%, even if you manage the transaction processing.

Comment: No Don,t want to give apple 30%,Is it possible..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you own the success page, then you could define your own URI scheme, that will automatically open your application on the device. This is how some links open the iTunes app, via an `itms://` URI scheme.

A good way to deal with this can be seen here:
[Possible to handle your own http URL schemes in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403992/possible-to-handle-your-own-http-url-schemes-in-ios)

Comment: You will need to somehow get the successful page (or a page it links to) to launch back into your app. Otherwise what you're asking for is not possible.

Comment: Can we able to compare the url ,if success url go to application payment success page and otherwice show payment fail page

Comment: What would compare the URL?