# Embedding a URL Scheme on a website?

Tags: html, ios, url-scheme

is it possible to implement an iOS scheme on a website via a script? Or do URL schemes have to be strictly embedded into an iOS application while in development?

Comment: please provide some more detail . i am not clear with above detail

Comment: I'm developing an application that needs to open interactive pdf's that with the ability of them being able to be edited. As iOS's standard PDF viewer does not allow this, I want to link to an external pages that runs a script which then opens the app „GoodReader" (if installed) with the respective PDF-File.

Comment: So are u trying to make your own url schemes , if yes, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403992/possible-to-handle-your-own-http-url-schemes-in-ios

Comment: Why do you want to make a web request for that, why not embed the directly?

Comment: @shujatAli: I'll look into your link, thanks! But no, I do not directly try to make my own url schemes, I want to embed an already existing URL scheme into a website instead of an application.

Comment: @leandros: As I'm currently not working with any iOS development tool but rather a  prototyping software which best capability for showcasing features is the ability to link to external websites, this is the best shot I've got.

Answer (score 0):

To open an existing URL scheme (whether registered by your app or another) from a website you simply place the URL scheme where you would in any other link

E.g. `<a href=myApp://>Open myApp</a>`