# iOS deep linking + redirect to App Store if app not installed

Tags: ios, url, uiapplicationdelegate

I've integrated custom url calls to link to specific pages on my app with the url scheme definitions like so:

```
myapp://?id=123
```

the problem is that I am not sure how to cause the iOS to go to the App Store if my app is not installed on the specific device, like Pinterest app deep links do.

Comment: From where? You're communicating between 2 apps, or 3rd party apps can trigger your app?

Comment: You can't, iOS doesn't know you apps URL until it is installed. Pinterets and Facebook redirect there normal URL to the app.

Comment: @rckoenes not sure what do you mean, Pinterest api will open Pinterest if Pinterest installed OR will open the app store. This is the exact behavior I want to implement but I'm not sure how

Comment: For example your apps URL scheme is `myapp:` then iOS will only recognize this URL id you app is installed. It will not check the app store for app that have an URL scheme `myapp:` like Android does. What Pinterest have done, It think, is redirect from there site to the app. Thus they can control the behavior, if the URL scheme is no supported they redirect to the appstore else they redirect to their app.

Comment: canOpenUrl method will provide you the false result and on the basis on that you can perform your own action.

Answer (score 4):

`UIApplication` has a `canOpenURL:` method that you can use to query the system to check if it can handle a URL with your custom scheme. If it can then you can open the URL and know your app is installed. If it can't then your app isn't installed and you need to push to the store instead.

This obviously needs to be added to an app, whether that be another one of your apps or a 3rd party app that you offer integration with.

If you mean from a web page then [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11588175/1988185).

Comment: The question was how to open the app store from a custom App Scheme if the app is not installed.

Comment: Good follow up, I linked to another answer that covers that at the bottom of mine as it wasn't clear in the question.