# Open iOS App by http:// link

Tags: ios, swift

I found a lot of tutorials about opening an app by a custom url scheme like:

```
myappname://
```

Thats nice but it would be great to open an app by registering the real app domain over the http link like

```
http://www.myappdomain.com/blablabla
```

So - for example - if a visitor comes to a webpage (on her/his mobile) it is normally opened in the browser, excepts the installed app is listening to the opened URL and opens itself instead of the browser.

How is this done (i've seen this at another app). Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible to handle your own http URL schemes in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403992/possible-to-handle-your-own-http-url-schemes-in-ios)

Comment: On your website you need to detect a mobile device, and figure out if they have the app installed, then you could redirect them to your custom url scheme.

Comment: but how can i detect if the app is installed on a website in browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a new feature in iOS9. It is explained in the WWDC15 talk [Seamless linking to your App](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=509).

You could also add a small piece of javascript to each page that opens your custom URL-scheme.