# How to open an iOS Application from Facebook,Twitter and Google+ posts which are shared from the iOS application using UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, sharing, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have shared few posts to Facebook,Google+ and Twitter from my iOS application.How can I open my app when users click on those posts I have shared?I have used UIActivityViewController for sharing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to handle your own http URL schemes in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403992/possible-to-handle-your-own-http-url-schemes-in-ios)

Answer (score 0):

For Facebook  you should use app links: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/ios. You can host links to your app with their hosting - https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=app-links-host
For Twitter you should use https://dev.twitter.com/cards/mobile/deep-linking but need the server side(hosting) with tags for link. Also, with default `UIActivityViewController` you cant do this.