# Deep link iOS with http scheme

Tags: ios, url, deep-linking

When I forgot my password, if a reset it, I receive a link by SMS. (url: http://www.example/forgotten-password/[token]

My goal is to open my iOS app when I click on this link. But currently, my searching display only custom scheme like myapp://....

Do you know if I  can use http scheme for deep linking?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to handle your own http URL schemes in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403992/possible-to-handle-your-own-http-url-schemes-in-ios)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Effectively it's a solution for iOS9 and above, but my app works on iOS8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a custom scheme like myapp://. [Inter-App Communication](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html)

In your webpage (example url http://www.example/forgotten-password/[token]), just redirect the user to your custom scheme (myapp://).

This way the user will click the link he received by SMS. It will open Safari and the user will automatically be redirected to your app.

Comment: This is not a good solution on its own, because it will result in a 'confirm you want to open this app' message on iOS 8+. The correct solution is to implement Universal Links (which don't have a confirmation alert) *and* a custom URI scheme as backup.

Comment: Yes, Universal Links do require iOS 9. However, iOS 9 and 10 now have [over 95% market adoption](https://mixpanel.com/trends/#report/ios_10), so anything that does not support them properly (e.g., a custom URI scheme alone) is probably not worth implementing