# is it possible and interaction between native browser and android application?

Tags: java, javascript, android, ios

good morning all, today my boss asked my an odd thing, and before telling him and the other programmer (who is responsible of this odd question) i would like a "different view".

let's assume we have a website, with a lot of web applications on it, some are games, but mostly are tech softwares, that people pay to use them for a given time.

so, at this moment, users come on the website with a mobile phone, neter thier number on a form, they then recieve a sms with a pin and with this pin they got access to some features and web software.

now, this programmer claim that he had already done a android application that can resides on the mobile phone of our customers, when they arrive on the webapp, the browser will delegate the application to do al the checks, so if the user is already logged, if he have to send an sms, and recieve the pin, or send back the pin to the browser to let him get into the application...

now...it is possible WITHOUT having the user surf the web inside the application (webview) and ONLY with the default android broswer? please forgive my bad english...i'm mesmerized by this situation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think there can be more than one way to determine it:
You can use a webservice that checks whether the user is logged on or not. If that webservice returns "user is logged on" you can use Javascript to open the application.

To see how to open the application from JS: [visit link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671634/create-a-link-that-either-launches-ios-app-or-redirects-to-app-store)

Comment: that should be a way, indeed.