# Launching another iOS app from the current app with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, automation, ios-ui-automation

How to Launch an iOS native app from the current native app

In Objective C I can write like

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"SomeApp"]]
```

How can I achieve the same in `JavaScript`?

```
var window = UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow();
```

Above code uses `UIATarget`,Is it possible to access the UI elements of the new app as it was launched from another app. I think it might not be possible,but I would like to use it for testing and I don't want to use Jail breaking.

If that can be done in `JavaScript`, Could somebody provide pointers on this ?

In Android, using some frameworks we can access the UI elements of any Application.

Is it feasible in iOS ?

Comment: Accessing elements in another app: I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure that this is not possible. iOS has very good sandboxing for Apps in order to prevent you doing things like this.

Comment: try to see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671634/create-a-link-that-either-launches-ios-app-or-redirects-to-app-store

Answer (score 1):

URL Schemes are the only way to communicate between apps.

[Communicating Between Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW18)

Answer (score 0):

When using Instruments/cmd line UI testing (Tune_up.js) you cannot communicate with apps outside of the target testing app. When your app leaves the foreground you won't be able to get it back except for one case.

UIATarget.deactivateAppForDuration();

This will behave as though the user has hit the home button, and after the duration goes to the multi-tasking board and brings your app back to the foreground.