# API of "Twitter for iPhone"

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, twitter

I am writing a custom app which constructs a tweet with a webpage link (mine) and send it to Twitter for iPhone (I don't want to handle the posting myself directly to twitter). Is there a way to use the API of "Twitter for iPhone"?
(Mine is a jquery app)
And importantly, I looking to POST MY TWEET and not display tweets of any twitter member!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you should take a look at available URL schemes:

http://handleopenurl.com/

According to the page you can do the following:

`twitter://post?message=hello%20world&in_reply_to_status_id=12345`

This question might also be helpful, as you need to somehow handle case when the app is not there:

[Is it possible to register a http+domain-based URL Scheme for iPhone apps, like YouTube and Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108693/is-it-possible-to-register-a-httpdomain-based-url-scheme-for-iphone-apps-like-y)

Cheers,
Paweł

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `twitter://` URL scheme.

```
<a href="twitter://post?message=hello%20world">Post a message</a>
```

http://handleopenurl.com/scheme/twitter

Comment: Do you have Twitter for iPhone installed?