# What is this website trying to do with this redirect? intent://someURL Android

Tags: android, redirect, android-intent

There is this website:

```
http://m.taobao.com/?sprefer=sypc00
```

When I click on the yellow button I get redirected to the following URL:

```
intent//m.taobao.com/?weburl=http#Intent;scheme=taobaowebview;package=com.taobao.taobao;end
```

I'm not sure what it's happening here, is that a valid URL to redirect to in Android?

This only happens in Mobile Chrome. If I use Mobile Firefox, or Mobile Opera then I get redirected to

```
m.taobao.com/channel/act/sale/tbdl1.html
```

My question is: 
Is it a valid redirect on android platform to some URL that starts with intent//? specifically:

```
intent//m.taobao.com/?weburl=http#Intent;scheme=taobaowebview;package=com.taobao.taobao;end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is valid redirect, it can open application on android phone.

Resources:

[Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

[Make a link in the Android browser start up my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app/3472228)

Comment: OK I tested by installing the application. If the application is installed, then it opens. I do have a problem when the application is not installed.

Is my application supposed to hand the intent to the Store Application on the device? Or should the store app know about it and register to handle it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518453/android-redirect-to-store-if-app-not-installed-launch-from-website