# Launch app in market if not installed

Tags: android, google-play-services

I can launch my app from the browser if it is installed using intent-filters. If the app is not installed, I would like the user brought to the app specific page in the market. I don't care if I have to handle this or if the platform does this for me, I only need to know how to set up the intent-filter, protocols, anchor tags, etc.

thank you!

Comment: slightly different. Really I don't care if it is installed or not if the platform is able to handle that aspect for me. I just either want the app, or the app page in the market launched.

Comment: A better duplicate question is [Redirect to store if app is not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518453/android-redirect-to-store-if-app-not-installed-launch-from-website)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "normal" way to do it. What you can do, however, is to always provide a link to your app in Google Play and have an intent in your app handle that link. Thus, the app will open when the market link is clicked if it has already been installed. The downside is if the app is installed, the user will be presented with a dialog and will have to make a choice of whether to launch the link in a browser or in your app.

See this answer for a code sample: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12901352/379245