# Android deep linking from uri

Tags: android, deep-linking

I am implementing android deep-linking concept and its working fine and my question is, I want to redirect the link to my play store application page if the app is not installed in the mobile.

Please guide me to find it out, Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11753070/8112541

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Deep linking: Use the same link for the app and the play store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28744167/android-deep-linking-use-the-same-link-for-the-app-and-the-play-store)

Comment: @ADM, this we can do inside the app but my question is I want to do this if the app is not existing.

Comment: See the first answer Its exactly what you need. Its need server involvement.  Server will redirect the link to play store not the app .You are looking for server side code [Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24464602/redirect-to-appstore-or-google-play).

Comment: Where do you want to show your deep link?

Comment: Thanks @ADM I will check.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29340428/launch-app-if-installed-or-open-google-play-with-install-referrer
Possible duplicate

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using this [Branch IO](https://branch.io/). It's much easier to implement in your android app. Follow this tutorial : [branch.io deep-linking](https://docs.branch.io/pages/deep-linking/routing/)