# Open a Url with option of Installed App and Browser in Android

Tags: android, deeplink

I have a String url. The requirement : On Click of a Button, the default chooser should open if the deeplinked App is installed with the User else opens the browser.

I am doing this onClick of the Button:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url);
startActivity(i);
```

The onClick opens the browser only, evenif the deeplinked App is installed. What should be the approach?

Comment: you can use share option.

Comment: you need to see this : [Make a link in the Android browser start up my app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app)

Comment: use:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518453/android-redirect-to-store-if-app-not-installed-launch-from-website

Comment: Take a look at this answer -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url);
startActivity(i);
```

The above code worked in case of deep-linked URL. The default chooser gave option for the App.