# Opening application from chrome browser url or redirect to google play using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, ios, browser, url-scheme

Im creating a website using MVC 4, and I have a need to within a javascript open an application, using an url-scheme (surfing the site using a mobile device) If the application is not installed, I need the javascript to redirect to google play.

I have looked and tried all various methods mentioned in threads like this:
[How to fall back to marketplace when Android custom URL scheme not handled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231085/how-to-fall-back-to-marketplace-when-android-custom-url-scheme-not-handled)

Many of those solutions relies on a timeout-event, which will redirect to another website if the app is not installed. The problem I am encountering is that after I have used the `window.location = URL;` in my javascript, any timeouts I have created seems to just dissapear. If i skip the `window.location = URL;` my timeouts fire just fine and redirects to google play or whatever. Does anyone understand why i am having this problem?

As I said im using MVC 4, and executes a javascript within a simple view. I have tried many different codes, opening iframes etc, all resulting in the same problem mentioned above.
I just tried opening the app, and delaying an ITunes redirect on a iPhone-device using Safari, it seems to work. Can the same be achieved with android/chrome?

I would appreciate any help I could get considering this.

Answer (score 2):

Opening an app using iframe is no longer supported by Google Chrome (v25 onwards). You can refer to the example on [Android Guidelines](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents) for opening the app (if installed) or redirecting to market.

Comment: Just for the record, the link has been broken, can anyone update?

Comment: for anyone looking for this here's the new link: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

Answer (score -1):

I love the Skype solution:

```
var element = document.createElement('iframe');
element.id = '_the_frame_' = ((new Date()).getTime();
document.appendChild(element);           
var r = document.getElementById(element.id);
var u = true;
window.addEventListener("pagehide", function () { u = false; }, false);
if (r !== null) {
         r.src = _customSchemaUrl;
 }
 setTimeout(function() {
 if (u) {
       window.location = _downloadIosUrl;
    }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: errors

at line2 (invalid left-hand assignment)
at line3, document.body.appendChild

also the script itself doesnt do its job