# How to not fall back to marketplace when Android custom URL scheme not handled?

Tags: android, google-chrome

I know that for Chrome for Android (versions 25 and later), I can use the [intent](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents) scheme to open app if installed, and if not, fall back to marketplace. But what if I don't want to fall back to marketplace, instead I want to fall back to another web page on my website? I can't find a solution for this, the iframe trick has been blocked.

More details:

1. We have a mobile web site, sometimes we send email with web page link out to customer, so that they can tape link to open our mobile web on their phone.
2. Now we want to send email with a special web page link, by taping it, Chrome is opened with that link, if app is installed, app is opened, if it isn't, user still stay at that mobile web page.

Thanks for looking into my question.

Btw, this is opposite to this question: [How to fall back to marketplace when Android custom URL scheme not handled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231085/how-to-fall-back-to-marketplace-when-android-custom-url-scheme-not-handled)

Comment: Why you don't process the link before user click it? Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116909/how-i-can-get-onclick-event-on-webview-in-android

Comment: @NguyenDoanTung Unfortunately, that link is a url link in email, not in a webview in Android.