# Android custom URL scheme with query string values

Tags: javascript, html

```
myappname://action?=login
```

The above lines works fine in some cases and some times not.

Then i referred  [android:intent://](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents#syntax) method

My URL scheme becomes

```
intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=myappname;package=mypackagename;end
```

it is working fine; but i need to pass querystring values as well

> action?=login

Please share your ideas

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary for you to use queries?
Why not include the *query data* in the uri like this :
`intent:/action/login/#Intent;scheme=myappname;package=packagename;end`
or
`myappname://action/login`?

From [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html) it looks like you can't specify the query parameter in the filter, but you might be able to access the whole uri programatically with **getData()** on the intent itself.

Comment: Yes i must use the query string... Let me check this and i ll come back to you

Comment: I must use instead of 'scan'?

Comment: I have tried both the links It is just opening the login screen; and not logining into the app      intent://url=https://webapp.com/&username=email.com&password=pass/#intent;scheme=myapp;package=com.myapp;end

intent://scan/url=https://webapp.com/&username=email.com&password=pass/#intent;scheme=myapp;package=com.myapp;end

Comment: You really shouldn't send passwords in a url.