# Detect supported protocols in browser

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web page, where i would like to add links using a custom protocol, to open in my desktop application. For example "myprotocol:www.mytestpage.com".

My issue is, how do I detect, using javascript, if the user has registered my protocol?

If for example I use the link above in firefox, withouth having the protocol registered, I am just taken to an error page. Instead I want to show a dialog telling the user to download my application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [simplest cross-browser check if protocol handler is registered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24779312/simplest-cross-browser-check-if-protocol-handler-is-registered)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect browser's protocol handlers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836777/how-to-detect-browsers-protocol-handlers)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot tell whether the protocol has been registered or not.

This answer should give you a step in the right direction. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24129863/7326037