# Check if App is installed from Safari using jQuery AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ios, safari, custom-url

I want to do an AJAX call using jQuery to check if the custom schema of my app is available, (in other words, if it can be open). The point of this is that I don't want to use a time-out like the other posts suggest, I don't want to display any alert if the browser doesn't find my url schema. So basically when I press on the button/link, I want to make this AJAX call, and on failure, I want to redirect the user to iTunes.
I will try this myself, but I wanted to see if any of you thought about tried this already.

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't the alert that is fired by Safari automatic and not able to be suppressed if the URL schema is not registered with the device? I could be wrong.

Comment: Yes it is, and I want to handle the missing URL schema through jQuery, without actually displaying an alert.

Comment: If it's baked into the Operating System & Safari, I'm not sure if it can be suppressed? Or have you seen a working example?

Comment: I haven't, but I am looking into it. I want to make an AJAX call, but I can't seem to get it done.

Comment: The only way that seems possible is with a timeout. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044805/how-to-check-if-an-app-is-installed-from-a-web-page-on-an-iphone

Comment: I know, but I really want to find a solution that doesn't use a timeout.

Comment: From what I've read (I did some pretty extensive research 3 months ago before the final release of iOS 6.1) the only way that currently works consistently is with the timeout. Otherwise, it looks sloppy. The user won't even notice the timeout if you code it correctly.

Comment: It is a good workaround, but I still can't get rid of the alert, and this is my ultimate goal.

Comment: Again, you cannot get rid of the Alert. It's baked into iOS.