# How can redirect webview controler to iphone app?

Tags: php, iphone, webview

I am trying to redirect my iphone app's webview controler to iphone app. so if anybody have done it then please suggest me some sample code.

i have tried this...

```
$query = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$homeUrl = 'demolink://oauth-response?'.$query;
$tryAgainUrl = 'demolink://oauth-response?'.$query;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, we remember you that this site is not a rent-a-code service. This is a site to help you with your code. So show us your effort so far.

Comment: check above code.....

Comment: And is it not working?

Comment: yes i have tried this but this is not working...

Comment: Ok I don't know if I understand correctly.. You want people browsing with their iPhone being redirected to your app in the appstore or something?

Comment: yes i want redirect from webview to app in the appstore

Answer (score 1):

I think your answer is here:

[How to check if an app is installed from a web-page on an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044805/how-to-check-if-an-app-is-installed-from-a-web-page-on-an-iphone)

The accepted answer explains how to redirect to your app if installed or redirect to appstore if not yet installed.

```
setTimeout(function () { window.location = "https://itunes.apple.com/appdir"; }, 25);
window.location = "appname://";
```

*Credits to **missemisa***