# HTML button to open Mobile Apps

Tags: android, html, ios

I am developing a responsive website and it will have a login button. This login button should redirect to an application installed on the users phone.

Is it possible to create an html/css button and once clicked, it opens up an installed application on your mobile whether its android or ios ?

Many thanks for your help guys !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044805/how-to-check-if-an-app-is-installed-from-a-web-page-on-an-iphone

Answer (score 2):

Open app: 
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/web-to-app-interoperability-launch-your-android-app-from-the-web/

Using an intent to direct the user to the app download page: 
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/web-to-app-interoperability-launch-your-android-app-from-the-web/

Comment: Do you have an idea how to integrate this with ios ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to some of apple's in-app url schemes, not all of the apps have schemes, but you might be able to find them in the developer notes of whatever app you're linking to.

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Marcel!