# Where should I put the google maps url scheme code?

Tags: ios, google-maps

This is a very amateur question.

The following is a code to check if google maps exists on an iOS device, as mentioned on the google maps iOS url scheme page.

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:
         [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
         [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://?center=40.765819,-73.975866&zoom=14&views=traffic"]];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Can't use comgooglemaps://");
    }
```

I am making a mobile website and I don't know where to place this. In my `JavaScript` file?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above code is Objective-C and is only for checking within iOS apps. For websites, the solution is to attempt a redirect to the app url (comgooglemaps://) and if it's fails then the app is not installed.

See more details at the following answer: [How to check if an app is installed from a web-page on an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044805/how-to-check-if-an-app-is-installed-from-a-web-page-on-an-iphone)