# Share page from Safari iphone to facebook native app

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, share

I'd like to add to my website a piece of javascript code that will share the current page to the facebook's user profile.
 `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={URL}`

It works well in the desktop version. In the mobile version it open a new Safari tab/window.
Is there a way to open the facebook native app with the share page?

Comment: have you looked at this page? it seems to cover what you are trying to do. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ui-controls#sharedialog

Comment: @Le Green: The page you shared is for ios (Objective C). I need Javascript code to run on the browser.

Comment: No it is not possible to open the native app

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this correctly, your question is very similar to [another on the website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25313299/how-to-open-facebook-app-from-browser-directly-to-share-view). To quote an answer there:

> The Facebook app does not officially support deep linking so what you are trying to do is not possible (right now).