# Facebook share deep linking - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, deep-linking

Based on http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook and [What are all the custom URL schemes supported by the Facebook iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707722/what-are-all-the-custom-url-schemes-supported-by-the-facebook-iphone-app/5707825#5707825)

I want to let the user sharing via Facebook app. (If the application not installed, I will use javascript like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044805/how-to-check-if-an-app-is-installed-from-a-web-page-on-an-iphone#answer-13196998).

I guess I have to use `fb://post/%@` but I don't know how.

p.s. Why Facebook not publish all of this? At least I have not found..

My JavaScript code:

```js
FB.ui({
  method: 'feed',
  name: name,
  description: message,
  link: location.href,
  picture: 'PIC_URL'
});
```

I am looking for a similar code in deep linking.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook does has a dedicated page for deep linking: [Deep Linking with iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/app-links)

Unfortunately, I can’t find deep link URIs that prepares or submit a message.

Honestly, I think using the FB.ui method is the best way, and I suggest sticking to that. Alternatively, you could look into other sharing tools such as [Shareaholic](https://shareaholic.com/) and [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/).

---

If you’re having trouble finding schemes, I often refer to [gotschemes.com](http://www.gotschemes.com/). This site is a huge database containing information about schemes for many different apps. But still, no traces of Facebook allowing you to set messages.

On a side note, the script you linked to is a primitive method. I’ve bundled several best practices in a little open-source project I intend to keep up-to-date with better ways to detect whether an app is installed or not. In case you decide to implement a deep link.

[Deep-link.js homepage](https://timseverien.com/projects/deep-link/)

Comment: But what is "fb://post/%@"? Do you know how to use this?

Comment: @mosh Where did you find that? I don’t think it’s valid... Anyway, they work as a link: `<a href="fb://post/%@">Do thing on Facebook</a>`. [My article about deep links was just published](http://developer.telerik.com/products/mobile-deep-linking-web-hybrid-apps/) :)

Comment: thanks for your answer. First, your article is just for whatsapp, and second, what "%@" means? How can I add title, caption, image and the other staff?

Comment: @mosh Nope, WhatsApp is merely an example in that article. “%@” doesn’t mean anything in particular. All Facebook documentation regarding the deep links doesn’t mention the ability to set a predefined message. That URI seems to be the only option Facebook allows.