# iOS App URL Scheme launch application or open app store

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, app-store, url-scheme

In iOS App, to launch an application from safari, the URL scheme is something like this, [Launch App from URL](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html) 
is it possible to re-direct URL to Appstore pointing to the App if the particular app is not installed in the device,
Basically what i am looking

- If app is already installed then let it be launch from the URL "**A**"
- if app is not installed let it point to app store and promot user to download app,

there are examples of [how to link to app to app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store), but not able to add condition in the js when to launch custom URL scheme if app is there, else launch app store.

Update :

the answer provided and in the comment take me to the page which says  **how to launch the app store with specific app** that's secdonary requirement, initially i need to have some js code which can detect whether the device has an app specific to URL scheme if not then open the App Store app page

element

Comment: I think if you point them to the web store, then the web store will redirect to the on device app store.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2337601/1178052

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to link to apps on the app store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if you can check if a third party app is installed on your device by code. I think only when you know the url-scheme of this specific 3rd party app you can check by

```
BOOL canOpen = NO;
    canOpen = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url];
    if (canOpen) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    } else {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:@"itms://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mensa-essen/id742570910?ls=1&mt=8"]; }
```

Comment: actually this is native code, i need equivalent in js, user will be on webpage and if app is there then launch if not then prompt user to install

Comment: sorry, i thought you need native code. Have you see this [Possible Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044805/how-to-check-if-an-app-is-installed-from-a-web-page-on-an-iphone)

Comment: Although the question was for a JS equivalent, it helped me out as I needed native code and wasn't aware of the canOpenURL check.

Thanks!