# Retrieving a deep link when the app isn't installed (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-app-invites

In the iOS docs for Google App Invites, under [Receiving Invitations](https://developers.google.com/app-invites/ios/guides/app#app-is-not-installed), it is suggested that a deep link can be retrieved on first launch if the app wasn't installed in advance:

> If the user has not yet installed the app, the user can choose to
>   install the app from the iTunes App Store. When the app opens for the
>   first time, the App Invites SDK will supply a deeplink if one is
>   available.

I've looked through the reference docs for [`GINInvite`](https://developers.google.com/app-invites/ios/reference/api/interface_g_i_n_invite) and [`GINReceivedInvite`](https://developers.google.com/app-invites/ios/reference/api/interface_g_i_n_received_invite) but I don't see any way to instantiate `GINReceivedInvite` outside of an `application openURL` call. Anybody know how to actually have the SDK retrieve the deep link in this scenario?

Comment: Judging by the [App Invites flow diagram](https://developers.google.com/app-invites/ios/) it looks like the install path leads to the same open -> process deep link path. Does the openURL method not get called when launching a newly installed app?

Comment: just once visit https://branch.io/ for detail

Comment: That doesn't help, it's a different product.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying I will say is not the correct way. You have to check in Safari web browser if app is install or not. If not navigate to App store

You can find your solution in here [How to check if an app is installed from a web-page on an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044805/how-to-check-if-an-app-is-installed-from-a-web-page-on-an-iphone)