# How do I redirect to the Apple App Store with a deep link? (e.g. a query string)

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, deep-linking, google-app-invites

I need to have an iOS user, who doesn't have my app installed, to download, then automatically navigate to a portion within my app.

Related, [is this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31857744/328397), but I am not exclusively reliant on Google's SDK.  I can use anything.

How can I

- Link a user to my app on the app store AND
- Have information (a query string) sent to my app on first launch

Comment: Your question title and what you mentioned in your question is misleading. TItle says how do I redirect to apple app store with a deep link, and in your question you are asking to provide a way to pass parameters to apple app store

Comment: are you talking about a link that direct the user to app store ? please clarify

Comment: @Mr.T Yes a link to the app store, that also works on the app if not installed.

Comment: In other words, how does App Invites from Google work beneath the covers on iOS

Comment: where you want to provide the link? on another app in your device? or on a website,so that when user launches that on safari and click on that link,takes him to the appstore.

Comment: What kind of info you would like to send to your app after the user install the app ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With deeplinks you have a link that is passed to the App whether it is installed or not.  There are a lot of posts out there about setting them up but here is a quick overview.

First you need to configure your App to handle them in the .plist file.  Here is a post for that:

https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios-9

You can either use a tool like [branch.io](https://branch.io) or set up a redirection page on your own website with an SSL certificate since it requires `https`.  (there is information in the link above, or here is some information from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html))

When your App is called by the deeplink (whether it is installed or not) the 
`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation` method is called in `AppDelegate.m` and the information you are passing is in the `url` parameter.

Here is a good post about setting them up.

http://blog.originate.com/blog/2014/04/22/deeplinking-in-ios/

Comment: OK so it's Universal Links under apple's naming, and after a quick read, it seems that the OS does a prefetch to apple-app-site-association to see if the transparent deep linking (after the app store) is possible.

Comment: If that prefetch thing is true, I totally get this.  Thanks a lot for fast tracking my development.

Comment: *OK so it's Universal Links under apple's naming* yup, good luck!

Comment: A more comprehensive article on setting up mobile linking: https://hackernoon.com/the-death-of-deep-linking-6cc65eb33e28#.avyz7g5bf

Comment: How exactly is `openURL:` being called if the app is not installed?

Comment: @mattsson As I recall if the App is not installed you are redirected to the App Store to install the App.  When you install and open the App your phone remembers how it got there and calls `openURL`

Comment: But how do we know when to redirect?