# How can I detect from JS running on IOS safari if waze or google maps exist on the device

Tags: javascript, ios, google-maps, mobile-safari

For a mapping website I would like to provide navigation information by launching waze / gogle maps/native map in this order of priority. 
Is there a way to automatically detect which app is available on the device, maybe by some kind of usage of their url schemes, or do I have to just show options to the user?

Comment: this should help http://stackoverflow.com/a/13196998/2286313

Comment: yes, the problem with that solution is that it requires to actually fire the app (which is ok for my scenario) and then wait for it to open, and only after the timeout try the alternative, which means that there is delay between the "click" and when the last alternative is used which potentially is a bad UX. But maybe smartphone users are used for things taking long time to open or I should profile the timeout to be based on the exact model.