# How to make duck in app?

Tags: permalinks, applinks, ios-universal-links

Some websites like Quora, and others have a, "open in app" icon. How do I do that and why doesn't stack exchange do that?

Comment: Awesome, Just awesome.

Answer (score 1):

> To add a Smart App Banner to your website, include the following meta
>   tag in the head of each page where you’d like the banner to appear:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID,
affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL">
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html

Comment: Thank you. When you say banner you mean something following across the very top of the page? In quota the icon is in line. Could there be another tag I can use anywhere on my page?

Comment: Hmm. Actually you can do that, but the application must be installed when a  user taps on that link. You can do that by using URL Schemes. Open  Info.plist file add a new item called "Url Types" and then add "URL Schemes" in it, set the value say "myTestApp". Then in you webpage basically add a hyperlink with the following format: "myTestApp://" (e.g. <a href="myTestApp://">Open the app!</a>). 
Voila :)

Comment: So the app registers a protocol like "myapp" when it's installed and then when i visit a page in the mobile browser and click on a link with href "myhref://something" the app will be open? How do you determine if the app is installed?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044805/how-to-check-if-an-app-is-installed-from-a-web-page-on-an-iphone