# How to judge some app whether installed in webPage on ios device?

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I want to judge some app whether installed in webPage on ios device, in webPage has a button, when click it, if the app installed , open the app. else open app store to download the app. How to achieve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if an app is installed from a web-page on an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044805/how-to-check-if-an-app-is-installed-from-a-web-page-on-an-iphone)

Comment: thanks for your reply!