# Graceful way to enable social sharing on Whatsapp via HTML

Tags: html, whatsapp

I'm using HTML to generate a share on Whatsapp button for a mobile website like so:

```
<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="whatsapp://send?text=https://example.com" data-link="whatsapp://send?text=https://example.com" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">
</a>
```

My question is that is there a graceful way - in HTML - to hide the said functionality in case the user doesn't have Whatsapp on their phone? If not, is there alternatively a way to show a graceful error in case the user doesn't have Whatsapp?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if an app is installed from a web-page on an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044805/how-to-check-if-an-app-is-installed-from-a-web-page-on-an-iphone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hassan,

A similar question has already been asked here.
[How to check if an app is installed from a web-page on an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044805/how-to-check-if-an-app-is-installed-from-a-web-page-on-an-iphone)

Short: There is no decent way to check, from a browser, if an app is installed or not. There is a work-around though. Please check the link above.

Comment: Ah, so a timeout, followed by a 404 page, coded in JS. Thanks!