# IOS iphone - open native app from browser with appstore URL fallback

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, deep-linking, custom-url

I am trying to display a message on some of my website pages for the user to open the current page in the mobile app. I have implemented universal links for specific paths in my website and when the app is installed, the URLs are opened correctly in my app.

When the user does not have the app installed I want to display a message (with link or button) that redirects the user to the appstore to install the app. I have found many posts/tutorials regarding this, but the solutions do not work anymore (using custom url schemes, setTimeout, iframes - for example, this one: [How to check if an app is installed from a web-page on an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044805/how-to-check-if-an-app-is-installed-from-a-web-page-on-an-iphone))

As far as I know, there is no way to detect in javascript if the user has the app installed, but I know there are some workarounds and the user can go to a fallback URL (the appstore link).

I know that Instagram has implemented this and it is working. If you go to a profile page, a popup will be displayed at the bottom with "Use the app" button. This will open the app if you have installed it, or open the appstore page with Instagram.

Does anyone know a way to solve this?