# Auto Close Confirm box after setTimeout() is completed

Tags: javascript

> **`login.service.ts:`**

```
setTimeout(()=>{  
           this._auth.refreshToken();
     }, 5000);
```

> session.service.ts:

```
refreshToken(){
        var r = confirm("Your Session is going to Expire.Click 'OK' to Continue or Cancel to Logout");
            if (r == true) {
              return true;
            } else {
               this.logout();
               return false;
            }
      }
```

**How can i close the confirm popup after the time interval is completed.**

Comment: You can't programmatically close a native modal dialog; it requires user interaction.

Comment: You can not close a confirm.... You would have to develop your own.

Comment: Use modal approach instead of confirm, it looks better with proper css and you will have control over it using JS.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` events are not treated while a `confirm` dialog is open. This is in line with the documentation [at WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#dom-confirm):

> 7. Pause until the user responds either positively or negatively.

The same specification [explains what "Pause" means](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#pause):

> 2. Wait until the condition goal is met. While a user agent has a paused task, the corresponding event loop must not run further tasks, and any script in the currently running task must block.

So, you would need to implement your own, non-blocking, mechanism, or use one of the many libraries that offer such a feature.

Here is a simple implementation without library, using a Promise-mechanism:

```js
function myConfirm(msg, timeout) {
    const inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll("input, textarea, select")].filter(input => !input.disabled);
    const modal = document.getElementById("modal");
    const elems = modal.children[0].children;
    
    function toggleModal(isModal) {
        for (const input of inputs) input.disabled = isModal;
        modal.style.display = isModal ? "block" : "none";
        elems[0].textContent = isModal ? msg : "";
    }

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        toggleModal(true);
        elems[1].onclick = () => resolve(true);
        elems[2].onclick = resolve;
        setTimeout(resolve, timeout);            
    }).then(result => {
        toggleModal(false);
        return result;
    });
}

function refreshToken(){
    var r = myConfirm("Your session is about to expire. Click OK to continue or Cancel to log out. Defaulting to Cancel after 4 seconds...", 4000);
    return r.then(ok => {
        if (ok) {
            console.log("extending the session");
            // do whatever is needed to extend the session
        } else {
           console.log("logging out");
           //this.logout();
        }
        return ok;
    });
}

// Demo: let the popup appear after 1 second:
setTimeout(refreshToken, 1000);
```

```css
#modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background: rgb(0,0,0);
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  font-family: "ms sans serif", arial, sans-serif;
}

#modal > div {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 280px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -150px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  background: white;
  border: 2px outset;
}
```

```html
<div id="modal">
    <div>
        <div></div><br>
        <button>OK</button>
        <button>Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>

<p> This is a test page with a test input </p>
<input>
```

So you need to add the CSS and the `<div id="modal">` element in your HTML. Then call the function `myConfirm` with 2 arguments:

- the text to display
- the timeout in milliseconds after which it will be as if the user clicked Cancel

The `myConfirm` function returns a promise, so you must await its resolution before you can know and deal with the user-response. For example, use `then` to execute your custom code.