# DeepLinks and proper way to deal with 404

Tags: android, ios, apache, .htaccess, deep-linking

so I want to have some DeepLinks on my webpage that fire up a mobile app I created on my mobile device using Unity.

The DeepLinks are constructed in a way:

```
myapp://view?itm=356723
```

Now, if my mobile phone has the app installed, it will launch the app and use the information provided by the DeepLink properly. If I do not have the mobile app installed, I'll get a 404.

**What I'd like to know: Is there any way to provide a special 404-page that tells the user to download the App with a link from the app-store instead of redirecting to the standard 404-page the webserver provides?** For this, I'd like to assume that I run on a recent Apache Webserver and have access to .htaccess and everything else. Even PHP is a given.

I know that there are sophisticated solutions for DeepLinking like branch.io but let's say I want to keep things simple and use this approach.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I saw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044805/how-to-check-if-an-app-is-installed-from-a-web-page-on-an-iphone but I think this is not really what I want to see as I have to distinguish between android and iOS.

Comment: You have to use AppLinks for that with HTTP protocol. Will need some server side work as well.

Comment: Vijaypalod is correct .U need some server side implementations also for ur goal what u want goetzmoritz

Comment: What kind of actions might that take?