# Is there a method to detect native apps from mobile safari?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, mobile-safari

I want to show a banner that links to a related native app from mobile web, and link to the app store/play store if the app is not installed. I would like to show different UI (download/open app) depending on if the app is installed

I know safari has the [smart-app-banner](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html), but this banner is not very configurable.

Chrome has a method [getInstalledRelatedApps()](https://web.dev/get-installed-related-apps/) that can be used to detect a related native app from mobile web.

Is there an equivalent way to detect a native app from safari?

Answer (score 0):

No, for now there is no particular way to know if the native app is installed on your device or not.

You can check some solutions here [How to check if an app is installed from a web-page on an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044805/how-to-check-if-an-app-is-installed-from-a-web-page-on-an-iphone)