# Viber not redirect to main page if desktop app isn't installed

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, messenger, viber

I try to use link `viber://chat?number=` that redirect to viber chat and in case while I have installed desktop viber app it's ok, but when I haven't, I expected that this link will be redirect to main page of viber with link to download app - and but it doesn't happen

Comment: `viber://` is a custom protocol. Your browser needs to know how to handle it. If the desktop app is not installed. your browser does not know what to do with it. How should your browser know, open `example.com` instead? This behavour is excatly as it should be.

Comment: okay, is there a workaround?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if an app is installed from a web-page on an iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044805/how-can-i-check-if-an-app-is-installed-from-a-web-page-on-an-iphone)