# How to redirect from Mobile Safari to Native iOS app (like Quora)?

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-safari

On my iPhone, I just noticed that if I do a Google Search (in Mobile Safari) and select a result on quora.com, the result page launches the native Quora app on my phone.

How is this done? Specifically, is it a detection of the user agent and the use of an iOS URL scheme? Can it tell if the native app is installed and/or redirect to the app store?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails: redirect\_to 'myapp://' to call iOS app from mobile safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525257/rails-redirect-to-myapp-to-call-ios-app-from-mobile-safari)

Answer (score 16):

I'm reposting an answer to my own related (but was originally Ruby-on-Rails-specific) question from here: [Rails: redirect_to 'myapp://' to call iOS app from mobile safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525257/rails-redirect-to-myapp-to-call-ios-app-from-mobile-safari/12558714#12558714)

You can redirect using javascript `window.location`.

Sample code:

```
<html><head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
      if (userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) {
        window.location = "myiosapp://"
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Some html page
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does not work on my iOS 7 device IF I launch the webapp from a webclip in fullscreen mode. It has to be no fullscreen mode setting for the webclip.

Comment: Is this a proper solution? This would force redirect the user to the application every time he/she opens the URL. which it's annoying.

Answer (score 5):

Just a small improvement of the JS code, if the app is not installed, it will send the user to itunes store ;)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // detect if safari mobile
    function isMobileSafari() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/) && navigator.userAgent.match(/AppleWebKit/)
    }
    //Launch the element in your app if it's already installed on the phone
    function LaunchApp(){
      window.open("Myapp://TheElementThatIWantToSend","_self");
    };

    if (isMobileSafari()){
        // To avoid the "protocol not supported" alert, fail must open itunes store to dl the app, add a link to your app on the store
        var appstorefail = "https://itunes.apple.com/app/Myapp";
        var loadedAt = +new Date;
        setTimeout(
          function(){
            if (+new Date - loadedAt < 2000){
              window.location = appstorefail;
            }
          }
        ,100);
        LaunchApp()

    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do trigger your application to be launched using [custom URL scheme](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html), registered by your application with the iOS runtime. Then on your website, write code to detect the incoming User-Agent and if iOS is detected generate your custom URL's instead of regular http ones.

Comment: So, what happens if they don't have the app installed?

Comment: Good question, because there isn't a standard way of handling this. But [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108693/is-it-possible-to-register-a-httpdomain-based-url-scheme-for-iphone-apps-like/1109200#1109200) is a decent workaround posted by another user of this site.

Comment: Where is the workaround for detecting if your app is installed without error message ?