# Directly return back to app from Safari without prompting the user

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-universal-links, custom-url

I have gone through similar questions and the answer to all of them is using custom URL, which I did implement. However in case of custom URL's, when the user is being redirected back to the app from Safari, there is a popup that says `Do you want to open (app name)`. I don't want to show this popup to the user , instead I want to navigate them directly to the app. How can I achieve this ? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: See previous answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688319/how-to-redirect-from-mobile-safari-to-native-ios-app-like-quora

Comment: @MarkS. Thanks for your input Mark, however, these solutions show a pop-up, which is something I don't want.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this with URI schemes — they will *always* show this alert in Safari.

If you want to route into your app without showing an alert, you need to use [Universal Links](https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios-9/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alex.

Comment: My pleasure. Good luck!

Comment: Do you mind helping me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44706216/universal-link-does-not-work-in-safari